# no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason my rails stopped working.

```
$ rails c
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)
```

but rake still works:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Did you have the same problem? bin/rails and bin/rake are still untouched.

UPDATE:
We dont use rvm.

```
$ which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
$ bundle exec which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
$ cat $(which rails)|head -1
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

UPDATE2:
Something went wrong here

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/ruby*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 Okt 22  2012 /usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6224 Okt 11  2012 /usr/bin/ruby1.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6296 Feb 15  2013 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 9047 Jul  1  2012 /usr/bin/ruby-build
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  481 Dez 10 10:17 /usr/bin/ruby_parse
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  496 Dez 10 10:17 /usr/bin/ruby_parse_extract_error
```

and

```
 ls -l /etc/alternatives/rub*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dez 10 10:48 /etc/alternatives/ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Feb 27  2013 /etc/alternatives/ruby.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/ruby1.9.1.1.gz
```

But

```
# /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: that is ruby/gem-space problem. please issue `which rails`, `bundle exec which rails`, and `cat $(which rails)|head -1` from the project folder, and update the post with results. and answer please: have you use the `rvm/rbenv`?

Comment: and rbenv? I strongly advice you to use rvm or rbenv to avoid the similar problems in future. But if you can't. you can try to replace default system ruby. It seems that your current system ruby is set to 1.9.1 please show output of `ls /usr/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it. Someone changed the script/rails file. Restoring the old version solved the problem. Thanks for all the help!

Still dont know why this file ist executed at all...